# How to change Flutter theme data color?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to change the color follow by the color code, but it doesn't work.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(#0A0E21),
        accentColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Above is the code I had try to configure, it suppose to have black color and purple color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in `primaryColor`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      // Color(0xFF0A0E21) instead of Color(#0A0E21)
      primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      accentColor: Colors.purple,
    ),
    home: InputPage(),
  );
}
```

EDIT:

According to your comment about appBar color:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      accentColor: Colors.purple,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
      ),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
    ),
    home: InputPage(),
  );
}
```

happy coding...

Comment: After I apply this code, it shows the original blue appbar and white background. How to fix it?

Comment: Answer updated according to your comment.